# Large numbers rounding AS3

Tags: actionscript-3, actionscript, rounding

I've a huge numbers, for example 1.98726575488820e+30, and i want to rounding it to this form: 
floor + "." (without quoting) + five-digit mantissa + "e+..." (if there is e) but I don't know how can I do it.
In this case: 1.98727e+30.

Please so much for help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Number.toPrecision](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/Number.html#toPrecision%28%29) will give you a String like this:

```
var hugeNumber:Number = Number("1.98726575488820e+30");
var rounded:String = hugeNumber.toPrecision(6);
trace(rounded); // "1.98727e+30"
```